# How can I create a Backbone View with two or more liked nodes?

Tags: backbone.js

Take a HTML tabbar as example. Usually you have a ul and a list of div's. All the Backbone examples that I have found, link the View with only one node by the 'el', 'tagName', etc...

HTML TabBar:

```
<div class=".tabbar">
    <ul class=".tabbar-header">
        <li><a href="#tab-cars">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-houses">Houses</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-cars" class=".tabbar-item">...</div>
    <div id="tab-houses" class=".tabbar-item">...</div>
</div>
```

Backbone Code:

```
window.TabBarView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: ???,

    tabs: [],   

    render:function (eventName) {

        // Render all tabs in this.tabs

        _.each(this.tabs, function (item, position) {
            // Render each tab with item.render()
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});

window.TabBarItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: ???,

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {

        // Render the tab header and tab content

        return this;
    }

});
```

I wish to add several TabBarItemView's to the TabBarView and each one creates itself the li node inside the ul.tabbar-header and the div.tabbar-item as content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written an article that addresses this issue: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/

It will show you how you can either use a single view to do what you want, or a parent/child setup with a collection view and item view like you're showing in your sample code

Comment: Oh, ok I have rewrited the code, and now it works ok. The rewrite consists in create two subviews, one for the navigation and another one for the contents, and then the tabbarview manages the new/old tabs. And the TabBarItemView have disapeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can go as far as to make a separate navigation view, and have the navigation add an item through the render method of your tab-item-view.

when you render the tab item view, you do something like  `navigation.add(new nav item);`
and also add a way to remove the navigation item.

or you can keep the navigation in pure html and append a `<li>` item with jquery / javascript when you are rendering a tab below.

can't give you a fully working example though, if you really need it i can probably make one tonight,.